# When trying to program Attiny13 with simple blink program avrdude shows "target doesn't answer"

Tags: avr, attiny

avrdude is giving me this error message when trying to program:

> avrdude.exe: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 
>   avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1 Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override this check.

I was trying to program this code when avrdude gave me the error message:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000L      
#define PB3 3

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


int main(void)
{

    DDRB = 0xFF;
    PORTB = 0b00000000;


    while(1)
    {
        PORTB = 0b000001000;
        _delay_ms(600);
        PORTB = 0b000000000;
        _delay_ms(600);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your device is bricked?

Comment: I'm getting this message: avrdude.exe: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
             Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
             this check.

Comment: Interesting. Have you successfully programmed any AVR mcu with that programmer before?

Comment: yes, I have. Done today

Comment: Check your connections. Also did you program the fuses? You could have accidentally changed the clock source to something other than internal oscillator. In which case feeding a 1MHz or so clock into the XTAL1 port would allow you to program again.

Comment: Tiny13 doesn't have a crystal resonator support on chip

Comment: Show the avrdude command you used and the schematic (include all components even if you think they do not matter) or photo of the board/wiring (make sure all connections can be seen by others). Is there any chance that the connections or supply voltage were unstable during programming?

Comment: @Josedearimatea you could have actually mentioned that you were using an ATTiny13 in your question from the beginning...

Comment: @Josedearimatea and in fact the ATTIny13 **does** support using an external clock...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ATTiny PB5 RESET pin as GPIO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303972/how-to-use-attiny-pb5-reset-pin-as-gpio)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303972/how-to-use-attiny-pb5-reset-pin-as-gpio), there is yet another vital bit of information you haven't told us.

You didn't say in your question that you have set the RSTDSBL bit in the fuse settings, but based on your other question it is clear you have. Once you disable the reset pin functionality (changing it to an I/O pin), you **cannot** use low voltage programming any more. You must use a high voltage (+12V) signal on the reset pin when programming.

There are examples on the internet (such as [this one](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/high-voltage-programmingunbricking-for-attiny/)) which discuss options for building a high voltage programmer.

Comment: I have one high voltage programmer, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

the code isn't the faulty point.

the error message is fairly clear: check the connection; check the connection; and then check the connection again.